# c++ library returns incorrect pointer to object in mac os application

Tags: c++, objective-c, macos, cocoa

I am writing Cocoa Mac OS application (10.9.5 Xcode 6.2).
This app use c++ library.
I mix objective c++ and c++ in mac os application.
So i have this chain of calls:

Button Click(Cocoa) -> Objective C++ object -> App C++ object -> C++ library

App C++ object call this

```
Client* client = ClientManager::getInstance()->getClient( url);
```

ClientManager and Client is inside C++ library and getClient always returns initialised object.

Then i call some functions of client

```
std::string encoding = "utf-8";
client->setEncoding( encoding);
```

And this function cause EXC_BAD_ACCESS with code 1 and with EXEC_I386_GPFLT.
Code for this function in library is

```
string encoding;
void setEncoding(string newEncoding){ encoding = newEncoding;};
```

I checked that destructor of client is not called and object is valid but for some reason address of client->encoding in MacOS C++ code is incorrect.

I have this addresses:

C++ library:

```
Client ptr: 0x102811c00
 &client->encoding 0x102811d70
```

MacOS C++ Application:

```
 Client ptr 0x102811c00
 &client->encoding 0x102811d60
```

For some reason client->encoding have different address for 0x10 in MacOS C++ and in library.

So, question is how this happened and how to fix this?

Comment: Looks like client is coming back nil. Have you checked with a breakpoint?

Comment: I guess this comes from the difference between C++ string and NSString in Objective C.

Comment: No, client is c++ object so it can be nullptr(not nil) and getClient function returns only initialised ptr so client is not nullptr and not released.

Comment: "difference between C++ string and NSString" is nothing to do in here, i call c++ library function from c++ in Mac OS application

Comment: Problem fixed by this topic http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35870040/с-sizeof-type-different-in-library-and-calling-code