# C++ sizeof type different in library and calling code

Tags: c++, macos, shared-libraries, static-libraries

I use C++ library in cocoa application.
And I call C++ library code from macos application C++ code.
I run into problem that Client class in library returns

```
sizeof Client 976
```

but in Mac OS application I have

```
sizeof Client 944
```

Client class https://github.com/eiskaltdcpp/eiskaltdcpp/blob/master/dcpp/Client.h

Why is that?

Comment: I can't quite make out from the question what the 2 different circumstances are. And without seeing the definition of `Client`, we probably can't tell you much.

Comment: Your library was probably built with a different definition of the `Client` class.

Comment: Depends on what your `Client` class is. Could be related to [memory alignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14510711/how-is-the-size-of-a-c-class-determined) including [inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/937773/how-do-you-determine-the-size-of-an-object-in-c)

Comment: There are endless possibilities, but we should not be guessing. Voting to close.

Comment: I added link to Client object h file

Answer (score 0):

After comparetion of Client classes i went to it parent class and found that one member (CriticalSection) of parent class (Speaker) cause this difference of size.

In header of this file i found that because of not defined macros Mac OS application use different definition of this class(CriticalSection) which cause difference of size.